# Possible to do a chained factorial method without a helper method

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm seeing if it's possible to write a factorial method as follows:

```
class InlineMath {
    constructor(x) {
        this.x = x
    }
    minus(y) {
        this.x -= y;
        return this;
    }
    times(y) {
        this.x *= y;
        return this;
    }
    factorial(n) {
        if (n == 1) {
            return this;
        } else {
            this.x = this.times(this.factorial(this.minus(1)));
        }
    }
}
x = new InlineMath(2);
x.factorial().factorial();
console.log(x);
```

I know this is a totally non-standard way to do it but was just seeing if this way was possible (i.e., only through side-effects).

But so far the only way I can figure out how to do it is offload it like so:

```
class InlineMath {
    constructor(x) {
        this.x = x
    }
    minus(y) {
        this.x -= y;
        return this;
    }
    times(y) {
        this.x *= y;
        return this;
    }
    factorial() {
        this.x = _factorial(this.x);
        return this;
    }
}
function _factorial(n) {
    if (n==1) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return n * _factorial(n-1);
    }  
}
x = new InlineMath(2);
x.factorial().factorial();
console.log(x);
```

Comment: It probably is possible… but you’re not returning anything in the `else` branch, so `x.factorial()` is likely `undefined`, so `x.factorial().factorial()` won’t work.

Comment: You need to always return `this` in `factorial`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**modules**

I would suggest writing your `math` module with ordinary functions. You can provide an `InlineMath` class as a thin wrapper around the plain functions. This makes it easier to write both the ordinary functions and the class -

```js
// math.js
const minus = (a, b) => a - b
const plus = (a, b) => a + b
const times = (a, b) => a * b
const factorial = a => a == 0 ? 1 : times(a, factorial(minus(a, 1)))
const math = a => new InlineMath(a)

class InlineMath {
  constructor(t) { this.t = t }
  factorial() { return math(factorial(this.t)) }
  minus(x) { return math(minus(this.t, x)) }
  plus(x) { return math(plus(this.t, x)) }
  times(x) { return math(times(this.t, x)) }
  toNumber() { return this.t }
}

export { math, minus, plus, times, factorial }
```

```js
// main.js
import { math } from "./math.js"

console.log(math(3).factorial().factorial().toNumber())
console.log(math(1).plus(2).times(5).factorial().toNumber())
```

```js
720
1307674368000
```

**have your cake and eat it too**

One understated advantage of the approach above is that we have a dual interface for our `math` module. We can use it in the proposed object-oriented way as demonstrated above, or we can use it with a functional approach -

```js
// main.js
import { plus, times, factorial } from "./math"

console.log(factorial(factorial(3)))
console.log(factorial(times(5,plus(2,1))))
```

```js
720
1307674368000
```

**low-hanging fruit**

Maybe it would be cool if `math` could support really big numbers?

```js
// math.js
const minus = (a, b) => BigInt(a) - BigInt(b)
const plus = (a, b) => BigInt(a) + BigInt(b)
const times = (a, b) => BigInt(a) * BigInt(b)
const factorial = a =>  /* unchanged */
const math = a =>  /* unchanged */

class InlineMath {
  /* ... */
  toString() { return this.t.toString() }
}

export { math, minus, plus, times, factorial }
```

```js
// main.js
import { math } from "./math.js"

console.log(math(5).factorial().factorial().toNumber())
```

(5!)! = 120! =

```js
6689502913449127057588118054090372586752746333138029810295671352301633557244962989366874165271984981308157637893214090552534408589408121859898481114389650005964960521256960000000000000000000000000000
```

**demo**

Run the snippet below to verify the result of in your own browser -

```js
// math.js module
const minus = (a, b) => BigInt(a) - BigInt(b)
const plus = (a, b) => BigInt(a) + BigInt(b)
const times = (a, b) => BigInt(a) * BigInt(b)
const factorial = a => a == 0 ? 1 : times(a, factorial(minus(a, 1)))
const math = a => new InlineMath(a)

class InlineMath {
  constructor(t) { this.t = t }
  factorial() { return math(factorial(this.t)) }
  minus(x) { return math(minus(this.t, x)) }
  plus(x) { return math(plus(this.t, x)) }
  times(x) { return math(times(this.t, x)) }
  toNumber() { return this.t.toString() }
}

// main.js
console.log(math(5).factorial().factorial().toNumber())
```

Comment: I love these dual-use FP/OO explanations you've been presenting.  Here, I'm thinking (or perhaps only hoping) that the goal was simply academic:  *Can we do this only through side-effects?*  I hope that's the case, because I find little use for these wrappers for plain numbers.

Comment: thanks Scott :) wishing it's academic as well. not sure what the OP's intentions are but i hope the code here demonstrates that untangling the class from the plain functions will unravel complexity and dissolve the need for "helper" methods. i also hope these demos open readers' eyes to practical ways to write object-oriented interfaces they may not have seen before.

Comment: As I said, I love this approach. I mostly avoid OOP, but when I need it, I will definitely use this technique.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple mistakes here.

- Don't reassign `this.x`, keep your instances immutable.
- the `factorial` method should not take a parameter, it should use the value stored in the instance
- consequently, the recursive call of `factorial` needs to be made on a different instance, and not be given an argument
- the `factorial` method must always return a new instance, not nothing like your current `else` branch.

With some renaming:

```js
class InlineNumber {
    constructor(n) {
        this.n = n
    }
    factorial() {
        if (this.n == 1) {
            // return 1
            return this;
        } else {
            // return n * (n-1)!
            return this.times(this.minus(new InlineNumber(1)).factorial());
        }
    }
    minus(subtrahend) {
        return new InlineNumber(this.n - subtrahend.n);
    }
    times(multiplicand) {
        return new InlineNumber(this.n * multiplicand.n);
    }
    valueOf() {
        return this.n;
    }
}
const x = new InlineNumber(3);
console.log(x.factorial().factorial());
```

Comment: _"keep your instances immutable"_ - why? (Not saying you're wrong btw)

Comment: @evolutionxbox Because otherwise it's really ugly

Comment: @Bergi I see, thanks for that answer. I added in the methods, want to post that into your answer and I can accept it? Maybe do the javascript console/code snippet if that works?

Comment: @evolutionxbox See my alternative answer for comparison :-)

Comment: @David542 Those are not the implementations I meant.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: *Why keep immuatable?*  Because we're not barbarians, here!  ;-)

Comment: @Bergi: If you're going to keep everything immutable, though, you're not doing everything "only through side-effects".

Comment: @ScottSauyet I wasn't sure what that part of the question is referring to.

Answer (score 1):

In the factorial formula `n * (n-1)!`, you need the value `n` twice. With a mutable math object, you'll need to clone it for the recursive call:

```js
class InlineMath {
    constructor(x) {
        this.x = x
    }
    clone() {
        return new InlineMath(this.x);
    }
    minus(y) {
        this.x -= y;
        return this;
    }
    times(y) {
        this.x *= y;
        return this;
    }
    factorial() {
        if (this.x > 1)
            this.times(this.clone().minus(1).factorial().x);
        return this;
    }
}
x = new InlineMath(3);
x.factorial().factorial();
console.log(x);
```

Notice that writing the formula as `(n-1)! * n` is not easily possible:

```
this.minus(1).factorial().times(this.clone().x)
```

won't work as the cloning happens too late. I recommend my other answer which avoids this can of worms…

Comment: oh boy, that's pretty tricky, thanks for taking the time to do this though, cheers.

Comment: one question though -- would your `minus` / `times` implementation require an `InlineMath` instance in the other answer, or could it be done with a number?

Comment: No, this answer works entirely with mutable stuff. One could write `if (this.x > 1) { const c = this.clone(); c.minus(1); c.factorial(); this.times(c.x); }`. Maybe that would have been even more educational?

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping this is only a proof-of-concept, and that you never plan on using code like this.  But a simple change to your code will achieve this "through side-effects":

```js
class InlineMath {
    constructor(x) {
        this.x = x
    }
    minus(y) {
        this.x -= y;
        return this;
    }
    times(y) {
        this.x *= y;
        return this;
    }
    factorial() {
        if (this.x <= 1) {
          this.x = 1;
        } else {
          this.x *= this.minus(1).factorial().x
        }
        return this;
    }
}
const x = new InlineMath(3);
x.factorial().factorial();
console.log(x);
```

Comment: oh that's pretty nifty, and actually exactly what I was going for initial. Thanks for that!

Comment: didn't see this yesterday, Scott. i understand your comment a lot more now haha. ya this is precisely how i would do it – and i can't believe i'm about to say this – using side effects only...

Comment: made a small edit, i think you intended to use `minus`, but now i'm realizing `times` is unused too. my brain is hurting trying to think of a way to write `factorial` using both. rollback my edit if made things worse, lol

Comment: Yes, that's an improvement.  I think the problem with trying to use both is exactly what @Bergi was describing.

Comment: Alternatively, we might do `else { this.times (new InlineMath (this.x - 1).factorial().x)}`.  I think I might prefer this version, but they are very similar.